# At the time when the volume and the radius of the sphere are increasing at the same numerical rate, what is the radius?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, related-rates

I can't figure out how to properly solve this. I attempted but got confused.

The radius of a sphere is increasing at a constant rate of 0.04 centimeter per second. At the time when the volume and the radius of the sphere are increasing at the same numerical rate, what is the radius?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have

$$ 4\pi r^2 (0.04\text{cm/sec})=(0.04\text{cm}^3/\text{sec}) $$

so

$$ r^2=\frac{1}{4\pi}\text{cm}^2 $$

Therefore

$$r=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\text{cm}$$

Answer (score 1):

So you have that
$$
V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}.
$$
You want to solve for when
$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dr}{dt} \Rightarrow \frac{dV}{dt} / \frac{dr}{dt} = 1,
$$
so just solve $4\pi r^2 = 1$.  The constant rate is irrelevent.